# Sending message from Spring WS client with empty RequestPayload

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wsdl, spring-ws

I'm a bit stuck here. We're trying to write WS Client using Spring WS. The challenge is to handle web services like getVersion() that do not need to pass any values to the server.

Here's a typical Client implementation you'd normally use:

```
public class MyServiceClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

public String getVersion() {
        SomeJaxbGeneratedClass request = new SomeJaxbGeneratedClass();

        String response = (String) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request,
                new SoapActionCallback("someNameSpace/getVersion"));

            return response;
        }

}
```

The issue is when calling getVersion there's no SomeJaxbGeneratedClass to be passed as a request since it's only requesting to get the version number. So my question is what should be passed in as a request (RequestPayload) in this case? Does WebServiceTemplate have another method that would work better?

Here's how getVersion is defined in WSDL:

```
<WSDL:message name="getVersionRequest"/>
<WSDL:message name="getVersionResponse">
  <WSDL:part name="version" type="xsd:string"/>
</WSDL:message>

<portType>
  <WSDL:operation name="getVersion">
     <WSDL:input message="tns:getVersionRequest"/>
     <WSDL:output message="tns:getVersionResponse"/>
  </WSDL:operation>
</portType>

<binding>
  <WSDL:operation name="getVersion">
     <SOAP:operation soapAction="someNameSpace/getVersion"/>
     <WSDL:input>
        <SOAP:body namespace="someNameSpace" use="literal"/>
     </WSDL:input>
     <WSDL:output>
        <SOAP:body namespace="someNameSpace" use="literal"/>
     </WSDL:output>
  </WSDL:operation>
</binding>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would argue that this isn't the intended use of a document driven web service, this is merely a RPC call over the web. Which imho is a bad idea... Just create a request and response message as you should with a document driven web service.

Comment: M.Deinum, thank you for your reply. You said: create a request and response message. The issue I'm having is with the request since there's no JAXB-generated class that could be used as such. It'd be helpful if you had an example of request and response messages. Thank you.

Comment: Just make up a type for the `getVersionRequest` and `getVersionResponse`.

Comment: Created both types. Now it's throwing this exception: org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.cvc.adservice.envivio.getVersionRequest nor any of its super class is known to this context.

Here's the getVersionRequest class: 

    @XmlRootElement(name = "getVersionRequest")
    public class getVersionRequest {}

Comment: You have to tell Spring Web Services which classes it can handle. You need to register a `Jaxb2Marshaller` and specify which packages contain your jaxb classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to give everyone an update in case you run into a similar issue. I got this resolved by switching from Spring WS to Spring JAX-WS solution using JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.